# Посчитать среднее по группам

Tags: sql, база-данных

Таблица с колонками: book, author, year, publisher, series, rate.
Запросы (pandas/sql) дают разные результаты. Как составить верный **sql запрос** - средний рейтинг издательств?

```sql
    SELECT publisher, avg(rate) from stat group by publisher order by avg(rate)
```

```py
    stat.groupby('publisher').agg({'rate': 'mean'})
```

Comment: Попробуйте `(stat.groupby('publisher'))['rate'].mean()`

Comment: Собирает серию, а не датафрейм. Я ищу именно sql запрос.

Comment: К чему сравнение разных запросов? Посчитайте один из результатов вручную и сравните с ответом запроса.

Comment: sql запрос корректный. Получится среднее значение для каждого издательства при условии, что в таблице stat хранится статистика продаж всех книг.

Answer (score 0):

можно попробывать так:

```
select 
    publisher, 
    avg(rate) over(partition by publisher) as rt 
  from stat 
  order by rt;
```